# Warning: Native component for "<component>" does not exist

Tags: ios, react-native

My project is giving this warning, which I found after trying to debug why my native view component was no longer showing. This is something that has been working previously, however, the Xcode project has been rebuilt recently. I'm using CocoaPods to integrate RN in my app.

I'm wondering if something has changed or if I have correct versions in my `package.json`:

```
"react": "^0.14.8",
"react-native": "^0.22.0",
```

The code accessing the custom native component:

```
import React from 'react-native'

var {
  View,
  StyleSheet,
  NavigatorIOS,
  Component,
  Text,
  requireNativeComponent,
} = React;

class JuceComponent extends Component {
  render() {
    return <ReactJuceView {...this.props} />;
  }
}

JuceComponent.propTypes = {
  // props to send to Juce Component
}

var ReactJuceView = requireNativeComponent('ReactJuceView', JuceComponent);
```

Comment: Please post an example of the code referencing `Component`. Make sure you follow the docs for your version. The current version has a different API than `0.22.0`.

Comment: @BradBumbalough updated, thanks

Comment: Thanks! what about the definition of Component? I'm specifically looking to see which syntax you're using. Are you requiring it from react or react-native?

Comment: Updated. Ive actually started upgrading to RN 0.26 now... but would be good to see what went wrong here.

Comment: My guess is that you've got a mismatch of versions. In `0.26.0`, you have to require `Component` from `react`, not `react-router`.

Comment: @BradBumbalough I don't think thats the issue as this problem occurred *before* I started upgrading..

Comment: Have you tried deleting node_modules and rerunning `npm install`?

Comment: Yep tried that. Rolling back to RN 0.25 now as I hit some other issues.. I'll report back if I find out what this issue was.

Comment: I have the same issue with my Custom Component. Any hint ?